# Bind checkbox to updatesourcepropery

Tags: xaml

I have a simple Class of which I have an observable collection:

```
public class Car
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Brand { get; set; }
            public bool HasSeatbelt { get; set; }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Car> _cars;
        public ObservableCollection<Car> Cars
        {
            get { return _cars; }
            set
            {
                _cars = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Cars");
            }
        }
```

In my XAML i have the following:

```
 <Button.Flyout>
                <Flyout>
                    <ListView
                  Background="Azure"
                  x:Name="ContactList"                  
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Cars}"                 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCar, Mode=TwoWay}">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Border Width="300" Height="Auto" BorderThickness="1">
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <TextBlock>                         
                                           <Run Text="{Binding Brand}" />
                                        </TextBlock>
                                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding HasSeatbelt}"/>                                      
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Border>

                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </Flyout>
            </Button.Flyout>
```

This presents a list of cars to the user along with a checkbox regarding the seatbelt-situation. I would like my program to react when the user click in the checkbox and have it set the HasSeatbelt-bool.

I have tried for example:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding HasSeatbelt, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

But it dows not seem to be enough to trigger the update-event. Any tips on this one?

Comment: You need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on Car

Comment: Thank you, It is implemented via RaisePropertyChanged.

Comment: You need to raise the event for the bool property, and for any other property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raise the PropertyChanged event when HasSeatBelt's value changes, so your binding gets notified

```
 public class Car: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool hasSeatBelt;
        public bool HasSeatbelt { 
                                 get {return hasSeatBelt; }
                                 set {
                                     hasSeatBelt=value;
                                     OnPropertyChanged("HasSeatbelt");
                                     }
                                 }
        //Same for other properties

        void OnPropertyChanged(string p)
        {
          if(PropertyChanged!=null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

I've just created a small example, just copy paste it in a new project, and see it working. (It's not MVVM but I'm sure you'll make it work for MVVM)

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <ListView
              Background="Azure"
              x:Name="ContactList"                  
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Cars}"                 
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCar, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Width="300" Height="Auto" BorderThickness="1">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock>                         
                                       <Run Text="{Binding Brand}" />
                        </TextBlock>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding HasSeatbelt, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window,INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        Cars = new ObservableCollection<Car>();
        Cars.Add(new Car { Brand = "Ford", HasSeatbelt = true, Id = 1 });
        Cars.Add(new Car { Brand = "Mazda", HasSeatbelt =false, Id = 2      });
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Car> _cars;
    public ObservableCollection<Car> Cars
    {
        get { return _cars; }
        set
        {
            _cars = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Cars");
        }
    }
    void RaisePropertyChanged(string p)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

public class Car : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    private bool hasSeatBelt;
    public bool HasSeatbelt
    {
        get { return hasSeatBelt; }
        set
        {
            hasSeatBelt = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("HasSeatbelt");
            MessageBox.Show(value.ToString());
        }
    }
    //Same for other properties

    void OnPropertyChanged(string p)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I am trying tu change a property of an item in a list. I am using MVVM. I tried adding you code to my car class but it did not work. (did not trigger an event). Im thinking that maybe i need some kind of bool-converter.

Comment: You don't need a bool converter, please update your answer with the new code

Comment: Try the example @bugsy

Comment: Thank you!
I got it to work after playing around with you example!